# Copying Type String Array to Range in Excel - Invalid Qualifier

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types

I want to transfer the contents from part of the a 'Type' array to an excel range (see example below), but get 'Invalid Qualifier' error. Any help would be appreciated?

```
Public Type typDetails
    firstName As String
    lastName As String
End Type

Dim userDetails(100) As typDetails

Public Sub test()

    userDetails(0).firstName = "Bob"
    userDetails(0).lastName = "Bobson"
    userDetails(1).firstName = "Bob"
    userDetails(1).lastName = "Bobson"
    userDetails(2).firstName = "Bob"
    userDetails(2).lastName = "Bobson"

    Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A3") = userDetails.firstName

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Comment: Which line? I doubt you can add all firstnames in one go like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Arrays: 0-based vs 1-based, 1D vs 2D

- [Workbook
  Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pu1hjxhiyb8y7f/copying-type-string-array-to-range-in-excel-invalid-qualifier_55301483.xlsm?dl=0) (Dropbox)
- To copy the data in one go you have to put it in an adequate array,
  unfortunately using a loop, but which should be much faster than
  looping through a range.
- The following are various options how you may achieve this.
- I have expanded it to include the last name, too.
- You should probably introduce a `long` variable for `UBound(userDetails)`.
- I used `Private` instead of `Public` to keep it on module-level.

### Module1

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type typDetails
    firstName As String
    lastName As String
End Type

Private userDetails(2) As typDetails

' Introduce two 0-based arrays (needs Transpose and 'size adjustment').
Sub test1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntFirst As Variant
    Dim vntLast As Variant

    userDetails(0).firstName = "Bob1"
    userDetails(0).lastName = "Bobson1"
    userDetails(1).firstName = "John1"
    userDetails(1).lastName = "Johnson1"
    userDetails(2).firstName = "Peter1"
    userDetails(2).lastName = "Peterson1"

    ReDim vntFirst(UBound(userDetails))
    ReDim vntLast(UBound(userDetails))

    For i = 0 To UBound(userDetails)
        vntFirst(i) = userDetails(i).firstName
        vntLast(i) = userDetails(i).lastName
    Next

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vntFirst) + 1) = _
                Application.Transpose(vntFirst)
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vntLast) + 1) = _
                Application.Transpose(vntLast)
    End With

End Sub

' Introduce two 1D 1-based arrays (needs Transpose).
Sub test2()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntFirst As Variant
    Dim vntLast As Variant

    userDetails(0).firstName = "Bob2"
    userDetails(0).lastName = "Bobson2"
    userDetails(1).firstName = "John2"
    userDetails(1).lastName = "Johnson2"
    userDetails(2).firstName = "Peter2"
    userDetails(2).lastName = "Peterson2"

    ReDim vntFirst(1 To UBound(userDetails) + 1)
    ReDim vntLast(1 To UBound(userDetails) + 1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(userDetails)
        vntFirst(i + 1) = userDetails(i).firstName
        vntLast(i + 1) = userDetails(i).lastName
    Next

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vntFirst)) = Application.Transpose(vntFirst)
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vntLast)) = Application.Transpose(vntLast)
    End With

End Sub

' Introduce two 2D 1-based arrays.
Sub test3()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntFirst As Variant
    Dim vntLast As Variant

    userDetails(0).firstName = "Bob3"
    userDetails(0).lastName = "Bobson3"
    userDetails(1).firstName = "John3"
    userDetails(1).lastName = "Johnson3"
    userDetails(2).firstName = "Peter3"
    userDetails(2).lastName = "Peterson3"

    ReDim vntFirst(1 To UBound(userDetails) + 1, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vntLast(1 To UBound(userDetails) + 1, 1 To 1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(userDetails)
        vntFirst(i + 1, 1) = userDetails(i).firstName
        vntLast(i + 1, 1) = userDetails(i).lastName
    Next

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vntFirst)) = vntFirst
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vntLast)) = vntLast
    End With

End Sub
```

### Module2

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type typDetails
    firstName As String
    lastName As String
End Type

' Declare as 1D 1-based array.
Private userDetails(1 To 3) As typDetails

' Introduce two 1D 1-based arrays (needs Transpose).
Sub test3()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntFirst As Variant
    Dim vntLast As Variant

    Erase userDetails
    userDetails(1).firstName = "Bob4"
    userDetails(1).lastName = "Bobson4"
    userDetails(2).firstName = "John4"
    userDetails(2).lastName = "Johnson4"
    userDetails(3).firstName = "Peter4"
    userDetails(3).lastName = "Peterson4"

    ReDim vntFirst(1 To UBound(userDetails))
    ReDim vntLast(1 To UBound(userDetails))

    For i = 1 To UBound(userDetails)
        vntFirst(i) = userDetails(i).firstName
        vntLast(i) = userDetails(i).lastName
    Next

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vntFirst)) = Application.Transpose(vntFirst)
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vntLast)) = Application.Transpose(vntLast)
    End With

End Sub
```

### Module3

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type typDetails
    firstName As String
    lastName As String
End Type

' Declare as 2D 1-based array.
Private userDetails(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As typDetails

' Introduce two 2D 1-based arrays.
Sub test5()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntFirst As Variant
    Dim vntLast As Variant

    Erase userDetails
    userDetails(1, 1).firstName = "Bob5"
    userDetails(1, 1).lastName = "Bobson5"
    userDetails(2, 1).firstName = "John5"
    userDetails(2, 1).lastName = "Johnson5"
    userDetails(3, 1).firstName = "Peter5"
    userDetails(3, 1).lastName = "Peterson5"

    ReDim vntFirst(1 To UBound(userDetails), 1 To 1)
    ReDim vntLast(1 To UBound(userDetails), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(userDetails)
        vntFirst(i, 1) = userDetails(i, 1).firstName
        vntLast(i, 1) = userDetails(i, 1).lastName
    Next

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vntFirst)) = vntFirst
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vntLast)) = vntLast
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Think you need a loop:

```
Public Sub test()

Dim i As Long

userDetails(0).firstName = "Bob"
userDetails(0).lastName = "Bobson"
userDetails(1).firstName = "Bob"
userDetails(1).lastName = "Bobson"
userDetails(2).firstName = "Bob"
userDetails(2).lastName = "Bobson"

For i = 0 To 2
    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = userDetails(i).firstName
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Data set is a lot bigger than this, and a loop would be too slow. Thanks for the reply.